# There is an unbounded continuous function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=-3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

**Question**

There is an unbounded continuous function to $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=-3$

I don't think so, intuitively, but how to formally justify it?

Comment: Simply notice that a continuous function on closed and bounded intervals must be bounded. Since every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is in one of such closed and bounded intervals, the function cannot be unbounded near any point! So, the only way a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded is that it becomes unbounded near infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

A function defined on a closed and bounded interval, by the Weirstrass theorem, is bounded. Like all points, $a\in\mathbb R$ is in a closed and bounded interval, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \neq \infty$ (equals $f(a)$). Thus, the only way for a function $\textbf{in $\mathbb R$}$ to be unlimited is if
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\infty $ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=\infty$ or no both no exist, but in this case these limits exist and are finite, so $f$ cannot be unlimited.
Am I totally right?

Comment: "the only way for a function $\textbf{in $\mathbb R$}$ to be unlimited is if
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\infty $ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty }f(x)=\infty$" Not true. The function $f(x)=x\cdot \sin(x)$ is unlimites, but neither of the two limits exists.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I was missing that detail.

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answers are missing the point a bit. The problem does not state that the function should be continuous everywhere, just continuous on its own domain (this is what we mean by continuous function), so it could be unbounded, as long as it 'blows up' as it approaches something out of its domain.

Take, for example, the function $f(x) = 1/x - 3$. Its unbounded, since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$, for example, but its continuous on all of its domain, which is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty)$, and both $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = -3$.

**edit**: this answer is no longer valid, since the question was edited and is now demanding for the domain of said function to be $\mathbb{R}$. So it would be impossible for such a function to exist because of Weierstrass theorem (and some other trivial details that other users have already mentioned).

Comment: Your example is not a "continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$", as the original question requires.

Comment: you're right, however, the question was edited, the original problem didnt ask for the domain to be all real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be s.t if $x\leq x_0$ or $x\geq x_1$, then $|f(x)+3|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow |f(x)|<3+\varepsilon$ (we have such $\varepsilon$ by assumption). Now look at $f$ in the interval $[x_0,x_1]$. This is a closed interval and hence $f$ is bounded there by some $M$ (since it's continuous). Take $N=\max\{3+\varepsilon,M\}$. This is the desired bound.

Comment: This is a pet peeve of mine regarding phrasing: *"if ___ then $|f(x)+3|<\epsilon\implies |f(x)|<3+\epsilon$"* makes it sound like an if-then statement where the consequent is itself an implication. In this case, the consequent is trivially true, so it makes the whole statement seemingly trivial. Instead put a period at the appropriate place eg "Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that____ then $|f(x)+3|<\epsilon$. Then, for all $x\geq \max(|x_0|,|x_1|)$, we have $|f(x)|<3+\epsilon$". This makes clear that there are actually two statements being made.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$g(t)= f(t^{-1})\qquad 0<|t|\le 1$$ is continuous and $$\lim_{t\to 0}g(t)=-{ 3}$$ Therefore it can be extended to the continuous function on $[-1,1]$ by setting $g(0)=-3.$ The Weierstrass theorem implies that $g$ is bounded. Hence $f$ is bounded for $|x|\ge 1.$ As $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1],$ we obtain the boundedness on the entire line.

Comment: Yes, but $D_g$ is not $\mathbb R$

Comment: It's not important. The function $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1].$ By applying $g,$ the function $f$ is bounded for  $|x|\ge 1.$ Hence $f$ is bounded.